# Create dynamic associated array from database fields

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I got a database with 2 fields: amount and name.
I want to get all the data from the database (40 rows) and create an associated array out of it like this:

```
$arr = array("amount" => "12", "name" => "John");
```

How is this done dynamically in PHP? I am stuck.

Comment: It seems you haven't done any research. A simple google query would come up with many results. Try one and come back with a specific question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the mysql_* function, you can do the following to get one row at a time:

```
$res = mysql_query("SELECT amount, name FROM mytable");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    var_export($row); // outputs array ( 'amount' => '12', 'name' => 'John', )
}
```

To get all rows in a single array:

```
$customers = array();
$res = mysql_query("SELECT amount, name FROM customers");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $customers[] = $row;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you run your query, e.g.

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT amount, name FROM table');
```

you can loop over the result like that:

```
$values = array();

while(($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))) {
   $values[] = $row;//$row will be like array("amount" => "12", "name" => "John")
}
```

and you will have an array of arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [mysql_fetch_assoc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php) if you want to fetch database rows as an associative array (the documentation comes with a good example, too).

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = $pdo->query('SELECT amount, name FROM ...')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

That's it in PDO. And if you're not using PDO, well, that's your problem then...